# Interpretation of Zeno's paradox in Gelfand's Algebra text.

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Imagine that achilles is running ten times *slower* than the turtle. The resulting geometric series will be: $ 1+10+100+\dots$ whose sum is computed to be $-\frac 19$. Previously in the text the original paradox is stated where the initial distance between achilles and the turtle is 1 and achilles is ten times faster. There the sum is computed using the formula $ 1 + q + q^2 +...= \frac{q^n-1}{q-1} $. Since $q=\frac{1}{10}$, $q^n$ will be infinitely small and is ignored giving us the sum $\frac{1}{1-q}=\frac{10}{9}$. In the present case where $q=10$, however Gelfand uses the same formula $\frac{1}{1-q}=-\frac{1}{9}$. Won't $q^n$ be so large that it cannot be ignored? Also gelfand declares that this absurd answer can be reasonably interpreted without any explanation as to how achilles meets the turtle after $-\frac{1}{9}$ meters. Please clarify.

Comment: You are right, you can't derive the formula $\frac1{1-q}=\sum q^n$ when $q\geq 1$ because the $q^m$ term diverges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for infinite sums. Just use the $v=\frac d{t}$ formula.

Let speed of tortoise = $v$.

Then speed of Achilles = $\frac v{10}$.

Distance of tortoise = $1+vt$ at time $t$.

Distance of Achilles = $\frac v{10}t$ at time $t$.

The difference in their distances = $1+vt -\frac v{10}t$ = $1+\frac 9{10}vt$ at time $t$.

To determine when they are at the same point, set $1+\frac 9{10}vt=0$ and solve for $t$.

$t= -\frac{10}{9v}$

At this time, distance of tortoise = $1+v(-\frac{10}{9v}) =-\frac1{9} $, and distance of Achilles = $\frac v{10}(-\frac{10}{9v}) = -\frac 1{9}$.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the sum $\sum_{k=0}^\infty 10^k=-\frac 1 9$ can be justified introducing p-adic numbers, which are a different way to extend natural numbers. In this case the sum would be $\dots 1111$ which is the 10-adic expansion of $-\frac 1 9$ . This is not a summation done in the usual sense, since it doesn't converge.
The usual formula to sum a geometric serie (in the usual sense if it converges, with p-adic numbers if it doesn't) can be derived in this way:

$S=\sum_{k=0}^\infty n^k=1+n+n^2+n^3+\dots=1+n(1+n+n^2+\dots)=1+nS=\frac 1 {1-n}$

Comment: Is there no simpler explanation? This is an elementary text and converging series and p -adic numbers are gibberish to me as yet. Also how can the answer be interpreted i.e. do both achilles and the turtle go backwards?

Comment: You can't interpretate this in the normal way of summing because p-adic numbers have a different norm (the distance between two p-adic numbers is not the same as between two real numbers, that's why you get a negative result) but if you want simply an algebraic proof just use $10$ instead of $n$ in the last formula i wrote.